# How can I addslashes() to elements of a multidimensional array? (php)

Tags: codeigniter, multidimensional-array, addslashes

I have a multidim array from my $_POST but I have to serialize() then save to the database...

Normally, I can serialize but I got some problem with slashes (apostrophe and double quote).

My array seems like this: $array["hu"]["category"]["food"] = "string";

But when the "string" contains "" or '' theres's shit...

I need some short code for add slashes, but thres a lots of wrong solutions out there.

p.s.: I'm a CodeIgniter user.

// update:

```
function addslashesextended(&$arr_r) {
  if (is_array($arr_r)) {
    foreach ($arr_r as &$val){
      if( is_array($val) ){
        addslashesextended($val);
      }else{
        $val = addslashes($val); 
      }
    }
    unset($val);
  } else {
    $arr_r = addslashes($arr_r);
  }
}
```

Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best solution would be to use the codeigniter input class and active record class . Addslasches/escapes, and most general sanitization will be taken care of for you.

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html